# How to allow everyone read access to s3 bucket as long as requester pays?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a AWS s3 bucket of data I want to make available to everyone but I do not want to pay for their bandwidth.  I already have the bucket configured for requester pay but how can I make it so anyone can read only?

Comment: Well, "anyone" in this case means only "any other AWS account", right? A simple GET without AWS credentials will never work. So who exactly do you want to grant access to? Simply any other AWS account?

Comment: Correct anyone with aws account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Amazon S3 buckets configured for **Requester Pays** means that the requester will be charged for **Data Transfer** costs. Since these costs need to be charged back to an identified AWS Account, the objects must be accessed via **authenticated requests**.

From [Requester Pays buckets - Amazon Simple Storage Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/RequesterPaysBuckets.html):

> If you enable Requester Pays on a bucket, anonymous access to that bucket is not allowed.

From [Website endpoints - Amazon Simple Storage Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/WebsiteEndpoints.html):

> Requester Pays buckets do not allow access through the website endpoint. Any request to such a bucket receives a `403 Access Denied` response.

The simplest way to obtain access to a Requester Pays bucket is to use the AWS CLI, for example:

```sh
aws s3 ls s3://bucketname --request-payer
aws s3 sync s3://bucketname/folder/ ./folder/ --request-payer
```

The AWS CLI will authenticate with AWS with credentials provided in the `~/.aws/credentials` file. The AWS Account associated with those credentials will be charged for Data Transfer involving the bucket.

Note the addition of the `--request-payer` parameter. From the documentation: "Confirms that the requester knows that they will be charged for the request. Bucket owners need not specify this parameter in their requests."

Additionally, the objects must be made publicly accessible by granting a `public-read` ACL, or by using a Bucket Policy, such as:

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:ListBucket"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::bucketname",
                "arn:aws:s3:::bucketname/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: thanks the ```"Principal": "*",``` is what I was missing